# Wildfly messaging stored in a JDBC datasource for several servers

Tags: wildfly, messaging, activemq-artemis

I try to persist messages from activeMQ messaging in a postgres databases. This first step was easy. I added this CLI

```
  /subsystem=datasources/data-source=messagingDS:add(jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/messagingDS",use-java-context=true,  \
    use-ccm=true,connection-url="{{ pg_db_connection_url_messaging }}",driver-name=postgres,transaction-isolation=TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED,min-pool-size=0,  \
    max-pool-size=20,user-name={{ pg_db_user_pg }},password={{ pg_db_password_pg }},blocking-timeout-wait-millis=10000,check-valid-connection-sql=select 1,validate-on-match=true, \
    valid-connection-checker-class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker",validate-on-match=true, \
    exception-sorter-class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter")
  /subsystem=datasources/data-source=messagingDS:test-connection-in-pool
  /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default:write-attribute(name=journal-datasource, value=messagingDS)
```

But i want to use the same DB schema for more than one server on a cluster, somewhere i read i have to use some suffix, but i cant find information how to configure a suffix per server in activeMQ, any idea how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe WildFly supports a suffix or prefix for the JDBC table names so you'll need to manually set the table names for the `journal` configuration. Here's the list of attributes:

- `messages-table`
- `bindings-table`
- `jms-bindings-table`
- `large-messages-table`
- `node-manager-store-table`
- `page-store-table`

These will need to be unique for each server.

Comment: Thank you, i think i have it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, i think i have it. This makes the tables unique and as an example i can use the tables for an cluster of four with giving every node a number. Automation makes this easy ;)

journnal for large tables are not implemented at this moment

```
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default:write-attribute(name=journal-messages-table,value=MESSAGES_01)
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default:write-attribute(name=journal-bindings-table,value=BINDINGS_01)
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default:write-attribute(name=journal-large-messages-table,value=LARGE_MESSAGES_01)
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default:write-attribute(name=journal-node-manager-store-table,value=NODE_MANAGER_STORE_01)
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default:write-attribute(name=journal-page-store-table,value=PAGE_STORE_01)
```

Comment: Did you mean to post this as an answer? This is the same basic information that I provided in my answer but now formatted as JBoss CLI commands. It's generally considered impolite to post your own answer using the content of someone else's answer.

Comment: i apologize, bu i was struggeling with the comment function, next time i try to make it better

Comment: It may be best to simply delete this answer at this point.